# Building a splash screen animation in Ionic framework?

Tags: android, ios, animation, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic Framework v1.

How can I create animated effects for splash screens for my Android/iOS app?

Initially, I tried `.gif` images but Ionic Framework doesn't support `.gif` images.

Is it possible to do an animation effect for splash screens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use view events to create your splash screen. This might help you 
http://www.gajotres.net/using-views-events-to-create-javascript-pure-ionic-splash-screen/

Comment: Thanks for reply, Your reply is quite usefull for me but actually i am looking for animated fire image on my splash screen. Is this possible. Thanks!